# How do I use secret variables in TFS 2015 vNext Build Definitions?

Tags: password-encryption, tfs-2015

I'm using one of my vNext Build Definitions to publish the assemblies to a NuGet repository, after a successful build. The NuGet repository requires my credentials for me to publish.

If I click on the lock next to my password variable and mask the password, publication fails. If I leave my password, visible to all developers as free text, publication succeeds.

I assume that when I click on the lock that the password is still saved, but encrypted. I base this assumption on the MSDN documentation [Use Variables [in TFS 2015]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/vs/alm/Build/scripts/variables).

Do I need to somehow decrypt this password with another build step, or should I just trust that no ill will come to me in this unsecured scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When setting up the build you can pass your secret variable in as a build argument like this:

```
$(secretBuildVarName)
```

I used this blog post to solve this issue for myself:
[Battling TFS Builds and Powershell](http://www.miguelalho.pt/battling-tfs-builds-and-powershell/)

Comment: This does work. I found that it did not work in my targets file, but passing it as an argument in a PowerShell build step did work. Thanks.